# Travelling with a Pet from and to the UK

Tags: budget, uk, international-travel, pets

What is the most cost effective way to travel with a pet (a chihuahua to be specific) from the UK to Europe and back?

It seems like no one accepts pets. Not flights, not coaches, not trains. If you want to go by taxi or pet cargo then you have to pay at least 1,000 pounds?

Comment: Even if a carrier would accept your pet, are you in compliance with the rules at https://www.gov.uk/take-pet-abroad ?

Comment: Swimming, or maybe a canoe, would be the most cost-effective.  But that's probably not what you want... this is one reason price-shopping questions are off-topic :)

Comment: @KateGregory yes I am in compliance with the UK rules

Comment: There's a link on the page Kate mentioned, which lists the authorised carriers and routes. Perhaps you could contact one of the authorised carriers?

Comment: [Seat61 has this one covered](http://www.seat61.com/dogs-by-train.htm)

Comment: @AakashM Make that an answer, quoting the appropriate parts! :)

Answer (score 2):

[Stena Line ferries going to Holland](http://www.stenaline.co.uk/FAQs/travelling-with-pets/can-i-take-my-pet-to-europe) will take them:

> Yes, you can take your pet on all vessels to Europe without them being
> subject to quarantine laws on re-entry to the UK. Your pet can travel
> in the car or in the on board kennels (where available) and you can
> visit during the crossing, subject to weather conditions and staff
> discretion.

[LD Lines ferries going to France](http://ldlines.co.uk/good-to-know/pets) will take them too:

> **ENGLAND / FRANCE ROUTES**
>
> LD Lines is authorised by the British
> Department of the Environment, Food & Rural Affairs (DEFRA) to
> transport pet dogs, cats and ferrets to the United Kingdom in
> accordance with the Pet Travel Scheme. You may therefore travel on our
> fleet with your pets, provided you have the mandatory papers.